# Apache Flink: Kafka connector in Python streaming API, "Cannot load user class"

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I am trying out Flink's new Python streaming API and attempting to run my script with `./flink-1.6.1/bin/pyflink-stream.sh examples/read_from_kafka.py`. The python script is fairly straightforward, I am just trying to consume from an existing topic and send everything to stdout (or the *.out file in the log directory where the output method emits data by default).

```
import glob
import os
import sys
from java.util import Properties
from org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source import SourceFunction
from org.apache.flink.streaming.api.collector.selector import OutputSelector
from org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization import SimpleStringSchema

directories=['/home/user/flink/flink-1.6.1/lib']
for directory in directories:
    for jar in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.jar')):
                sys.path.append(jar)

from org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka import FlinkKafkaConsumer09

props = Properties()
config = {"bootstrap_servers": "localhost:9092",
          "group_id": "flink_test",
          "topics": ["TopicCategory-TopicName"]}
props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", config['bootstrap_servers'])
props.setProperty("group_id", config['group_id'])
props.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")

def main(factory):
    consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer09([config["topics"]], SimpleStringSchema(), props)

    env = factory.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_java_source(consumer) \
        .output()
    env.execute()
```

I grabbed a handful of jar files from the maven repos, namely `flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11-1.6.1.jar`, `flink-connector-kafka-base_2.11-1.6.1.jar` and `kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar` and copied them in Flink's `lib` directory. Unless I misunderstood the documentation, this should suffice for Flink to load the kafka connector. Indeed, if I remove any of these jars the import fails, but this doesn't seem to be enough to actually invoke the plan.
Adding a for loop to dynamically add these to `sys.path` didn't work either. Here's what gets printed in the console:

```
Starting execution of program
Failed to run plan: null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/flink_streaming_plan_9cfed4d9-0288-429c-99ac-df02c86922ec/read_from_kafka.py", line 32, in main
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:267)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:486)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1511)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.python.api.environment.PythonStreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(PythonStreamExecutionEnvironment.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed. (JobID: bbcc0cb2c4fe6e3012d228b06b270eba)

The program didn't contain a Flink job. Perhaps you forgot to call execute() on the execution environment.
```

This is what I see in the logs:

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot load user class:    org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09
ClassLoader info: URL ClassLoader:
    file: '/tmp/blobStore-9f6930fa-f1cf-4851-a0bf-2e620391596f/job_ca486746e7feb42d2d162026b74e9935/blob_p-9321896d165fec27a617d44ad50e3ef09c3211d9-405ccc9b490fa1e1348f0a76b1a48887' (valid JAR)
Class not resolvable through given classloader.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperator(StreamConfig.java:236)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:267)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there a way to fix this and make the connector available to Python? I suspect this is a Classloader issue with Jython, but I don't know how to investigate further (also given that I have no knowledge of Java). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong Kafka consumer here. In your code, it is `FlinkKafkaConsumer09`, but the lib you are using is `flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11-1.6.1.jar`, which is for `FlinkKafkaConsumer011`. Try to replace `FlinkKafkaConsumer09` with this `FlinkKafkaConsumer011`, or use the lib file `flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11-1.6.1.jar` instead of current one.

Comment: Apologies, I actually had `flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11-1.6.1.jar` in my `lib` directory, not `0.11`, this was only a typo in my post (now edited) The initial issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

I guest the jar file may has built-in import or dependencies,so the three jar files isn't enough.As to how to find out java jar dependent relations,that is what java maven do. You can see the official website "project build setup" for help.
In my case,i follow official java project setup,use "from org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka import FlinkKafkaConsumer" and add dependency "
               org.apache.flink
               flink-clients_2.11
               1.8.0 " to pom.xml,then i can output kafka records to stdout now with the Python API.