# Kafka Connector on Python API for Apache Flink

Tags: python, apache-flink

I could not find any working example of how to use the Kafka connector together with Apache Flink Python API.

Could anyone provide a working example?

Comment: Maybe http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Using-a-custom-DeserializationSchema-with-Kafka-and-Python-td22094.html#a22123 will help.

Comment: I followed these steps and got it running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744277/apache-flink-kafka-connector-in-python-streaming-api-cannot-load-user-class