# Kafka Flink using Python

Tags: python, apache-flink

I cannot see much about kafka flink connector python API.I came to know that it is in beta version.can i use kafkaflink connector API using python.If yes suggest me an program for this connector.
I also refered to [Apache Flink: Kafka connector in Python streaming API, "Cannot load user class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744277/apache-flink-kafka-connector-in-python-streaming-api-cannot-load-user-class).Also can i use the concept oof sliding window using python API.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to the Table API there's some support for Python in Flink 1.9, and more coming soon in version 1.10.

Sliding windows work fine with Kafka and Python via the Table API in Flink 1.9. See [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tableApi.html#slide-sliding-windows) for sliding windows, and Kafka, see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#kafka-connector).